# MS SQL - cannot find file path in backup file

Tags: sql-server, windows, backup

I tried to find daily backup files on my Windows server, but I can't find it. I  found latest backup file, but I don't see file path under "physical_device_name". They don't have a path (.bak) but a code like this: "{B7A4....}8".

What it this means? Crypt? Error?

[Link](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2960/sql-server-backup-paths-and-file-management/)

Comment: What command are you using to do the backup? Is it a third party tool?

Comment: These are not backups made sy SQL Server, but backups made by some other tool based on vss writer